# wkhtmltopdf get CalledProcessError under uwsgi environment

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wkhtmltopdf, django-wkhtmltopdf

I get a CalledProcessError under uwsgi environment, while I can run it in django normal runserver-mode ,and can run this command directly in command line correctly. here is my environment:
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://x/api/sheet/?order=1784285260

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wkhtmltopdf',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_crontab',
 'backend',
 'api',
 'website']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Traceback:

```
File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py" in rendered_content
  78.             cmd_options=cmd_options

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in render_pdf_from_template
  186.                           cmd_options=cmd_options)

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in convert_to_pdf
  124.     return wkhtmltopdf(pages=filename, **cmd_options)

File "/www/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py" in wkhtmltopdf
  110.     return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py" in check_output
  336.                **kwargs).stdout

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py" in run
  418.                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

Exception Type: CalledProcessError at /api/sheet/
Exception Value: Command '['/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh', '--dpi', '300', '--encoding', 'utf-8', '--margin-left', '20', '--margin-top', '10', '--orientation', 'Landscape', '--page-size', 'A4', '--print-media-type', '--quiet', '--zoom', '0.88', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdf0fjtzvle.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 126.
```

and my uwsgi configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugin = python36
socket = /tmp/site.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4
virtualenv = /www/env/
home = /www/env
chdir = /www/site/
module = site.wsgi
chomod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

wkhtmltopdf.sh:
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" 
/root/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf "$@"
```

I have chown the wkhtmltopdf to www-data:www-data, this still can't work,I don't know if it's about privilege.
and my wkhtmltopdf version is wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt), I try to get the stderr output from wkhtmltopdf, but i can just get stdout only